# Search API on Youtube TV

Tags: youtube-api

I need to build a system that uses an API that searches for Youtube content, with functionality exactly as described by https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters, but where the results are shown in youtube/**tv** (i.e. accessible and browsable just using cursor keys, select and back, as used in https://www.youtube.com/tv#/browse)

Having searched extensively, I cannot find a solution. Does one exist?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

If I were to interpret your question broadly, it would be "is there an open source version of youtube.com/tv that I could repurpose". The answer to that is no. You're going to have to do some heavy lifting yourself.

If you want a starting off point, you could take a look at the JavaScript source for http://stb-web-app.appspot.com/static/index.html, either just directly from within a browser's development tools or from the [SVN repo](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/ytplayer/stb-web-app%253Fstate%253Dclosed). That example doesn't give you exactly what you're looking for, but it does illustrate how to detect specific key presses and display YouTube feeds in a "set top box" environment.